# Search a string start with a letter and replace its nth column value with another file value

Tags: awk

I am trying to search a string start with H, C, O, N, S and replace its 14, 15 and 16th column value with the values from other file name frac (line by line). I tried make the one line script with following awk command but it doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
awk -v c="`cat frac`" 'BEGIN {n=split(c,frac," "); ifrac=0} { printf("%s",$0); if ($1=="^H|^C|^O|^N|^S"){printf ("%2.5f %2.5f %2.5f", frac[++ifrac], $14, $15, $16); for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {printf("%6d.",$i);}} printf ("\n")}' file
```

The file where I want to make changes looks like as follows,eg: for the first line start with letter C, I want to change the value of coulmn 14, 15 and 16 with the 0.29035 0.05915 -0.06369 from frac file.

```
C(5HFE  )  1  2 3304 3122 3124      1    3   28    4    1   99  0.28098  0.04363  0.00841  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  3.9170  0.0000  0.0560  0.0000  0.0000 -0.1800  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0290  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0300  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -0.2640  0.0000  0.0200  0.0000  0.0000
 -0.0190  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
H(5HFF  )  3  2 3122 3123 3124      1    2   24    4    1   95  0.27093  0.03969  0.00791  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  1.0440  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1820  0.0860  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
C(5HFG  )  1  2 3304 3124 3122      1    3   28    4    1   99  0.28246  0.05703  0.01056  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  3.9170  0.0000  0.0560  0.0000  0.0000 -0.1800  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0290  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0300  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -0.2640  0.0000  0.0200  0.0000  0.0000
 -0.0190  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
H(5HFH  )  3  2 3124 3125 3122      1    2   24    4    1   95  0.27416  0.06383  0.01183  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  1.0440  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1820  0.0860  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
C(5HFI  )  3  1 3110 3126 3128      1    3   35    4    1  363  0.29880  0.08862 -0.01177  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  4.0465  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0810  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.2750  0.0000
  0.3130  0.0000  0.0000 -0.2320  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0400  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0430  0.0000
```

here is how the frac file look like

```
0.29035 0.05915 -0.06369
0.28657 0.07680 -0.05079
0.28180 0.08165 -0.05931
0.27456 0.07357 -0.04197
0.27485 0.07855 -0.03091
```

Expected outcome:

```
C(5HFE  )  1  2 3304 3122 3124      1    3   28    4    1   99  0.29035 0.05915 -0.06369  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  3.9170  0.0000  0.0560  0.0000  0.0000 -0.1800  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0290  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0300  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -0.2640  0.0000  0.0200  0.0000  0.0000
 -0.0190  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
H(5HFF  )  3  2 3122 3123 3124      1    2   24    4    1   95  0.28657 0.07680 -0.05079  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  1.0440  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1820  0.0860  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
C(5HFG  )  1  2 3304 3124 3122      1    3   28    4    1   99  0.28180 0.08165 -0.05931  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  3.9170  0.0000  0.0560  0.0000  0.0000 -0.1800  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0290  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0300  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -0.2640  0.0000  0.0200  0.0000  0.0000
 -0.0190  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
H(5HFH  )  3  2 3124 3125 3122      1    2   24    4    1   95  0.27456 0.07357 -0.04197  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  1.0440  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1820  0.0860  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
C(5HFI  )  3  1 3110 3126 3128      1    3   35    4    1  363  0.27485 0.07855 -0.03091  1.0000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  4.0465  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0810  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.2750  0.0000
  0.3130  0.0000  0.0000 -0.2320  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0400  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0430  0.0000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR      {a[NR]=$0; next} 
     /^H|C|O|N|S/ {split(a[++i], b); $14=b[1]; $15=b[2]; $16=b[3]}
1' frac file
```

first pass `frac` and store the lines, second pass `file` and replace what you want.

I have assumed that number of lines in `frac` will be same with the matched lines in `file`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and code, but unfortunately I have 185 line just above where the lines are stating with H, C, O, N, S. But I slightly modified you code and it got worked as expected. Thought you are right that lines starting with H, C, O, N, S are same as in frac.  

    awk 'FNR==NR      {a[NR]=$0; next} 
     /^H|^C|^O|^N|^S/ {split(a[++i], b); $14=b[1]; $15=b[2]; $16=b[3]}
    1' frac file

Comment: Please accept the answer that best solves your problem, if any, by pressing the [checkmark sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) . This gives the respondent with the best answer 15 points of reputation. It is not subtracted (as some people seem to think) from the original-poster's reputation points ;-)